# gephi-toolkit compiled but won't work in app

Tags: gephi

I tried to embed gephi-toolkit in my java application. Started with simple examples on their Toolkit portal page. but it failed at the very first sample Headless Gephi, here is where it failed:

```
//Get Centrality
GraphDistance distance = new GraphDistance();
distance.setDirected(true);
distance.execute(graphModel, attributeModel);
```

it said:

```
[ERROR] class file for org.gephi.graph.api.HierarchicalGraph not found
[ERROR] distance.execute(graphModel, attributeModel);
```

i tried to dig their source code, seems that class is not available, but checked their api, it's listed there. so weird. anyone got the same issue? i m using their latest version 0.9-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be that the version 0.9 is being currently under intense refactoring and is unstable. You can download a stable version of the toolkit here: http://gephi.org/toolkit/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the attributeModel portion:

```
distance.execute(graphModel, attributeModel);
```

becomes

```
distance.execute(graphModel);
```

As of Gephi 0.9.0, the attributeModel was refactored and made part of the [GraphModel](https://github.com/gephi/gephi/releases/tag/v0.9.0).